# Need Help Getting Classes to Interact With Each Other

Tags: c++, class, oop, object

So basically, I have to write a program that is kind of like an RPG game where there are different types of creatures. Each creature is an object of the class Creature, and has member variables for hitpoints, strength, etc.

What I am having trouble with is writing the function that handles dealing and taking damage between the classes.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

//Creature Base Class (Type 0)
class Creature
{
  public:
    Creature(int, int, int);
    int gettype() {return type;}
    int getstrength(){return strength;}
    int gethitpoints() {return hitpoints;}
    void sethitpoints(int);
    string getspecies();
    void printstats();
    void dealdamage(Creature, Creature);
    void takedamage(int);

  private:
    int type;
    int strength;
    int hitpoints;
};

Creature::Creature(int t, int s, int hp)
{
  type = t;
  strength = s;
  hitpoints = hp;
}

void Creature::printstats()
{
  cout << "This creature has: " << endl;
  cout << strength << " strength" << endl;
  cout << hitpoints << " hitpoints" << endl;
  cout << "and is of type " << type << "(" << getspecies() << ")" << endl;
}

void Creature::sethitpoints(int a)
{
  hitpoints = a;
}

string Creature::getspecies()
{
  switch(type)
  {
    case 0: return "Creature";
    case 1: return "Human";
    case 2: return "Elf";
    case 3: return "Demon";
    case 4: return "Balrog";
    case 5: return "Cyberdemon";
  }
}

void Creature::dealdamage(Creature dealer, Creature target)
{
  srand(5);
  int damage;
  damage = rand() % strength+1;
  cout << dealer.getspecies() << " inflicts " << damage;
  cout << " damage to " << target.getspecies() << "!" << endl;
  target.takedamage(damage);
}

void Creature::takedamage(int damage)
{
  sethitpoints((gethitpoints()-damage));
}

int main()
{
  Creature monster1(0, 10, 100);
  Creature monster2(1, 7, 90);

  monster1.printstats();
  monster2.printstats();

  monster1.dealdamage(monster1, monster2);
  monster2.printstats();

  return 0;
}
```

Right now, the output the program gives me is:

```
This creature has:
10 strength
100 hitpoints
and is of type 0(Creature)
This creature has:
7 strength
90 hitpoints
and is of type 1(Human)
Creature inflicts 5 damage to human!
This creature has:
7 strength
90 hitpoints
and is of type 1(Human)
```

So the dealdamage() function seems to be working, but the takedamage() function is not properly changing the hitpoints of the creature that is taking the damage.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The `dealdamage` function takes `Creature`s by value - you're modifying the hitpoints of a local copy. Try passing by reference instead.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured out that I needed to pass the target class by reference.

Comment: You will notice a distinct lack of randomness in the damage numbers from `Creature::dealdamage`. Your call to `srand(5)` at the beginning of the function is basically telling the random number generator to start over at the same point in the random number sequence every single time you call `dealdamage`. You should call `srand` exactly once, probably in `main`, to seed the RNG.

Comment: Also, when you call strand, you have to seed it with the time if you want it to be really psudo-random, otherwise it's just going to give the same result every time you run the program. 
Make sure you include <time.h> and then call
srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

Make sure to do this only once, probably in main, as Casey pointed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is
   void Creature::dealdamage(Creature dealer, Creature target)

Firstly, this is called "pass by value". New "Creature" objects are constructed and the values of the "Creature" objects you call the function with are copied into them. The procedure executes, and these temporary Creature objects EOL - the original Creature objects are never touched.

You need to take a pointer or a reference to the original object. But unless you are intending to support some kind of 3-way fight, you shouldn't be requiring both items anyway -- this is a non-static member function, so it's already operating in the context of one of the creatures, hence the syntax with which you invoked it:
    monster1.dealdamage(monster1, monster2);

Change your dealdamage like this:

```
void Creature::dealdamage(Creature& target) // takes a reference
{
    //srand(5); <- this will cause rand() to always return the same value. dont do it.
    //int damage; <- don't separate declaration and assignment when you can avoid it.
    int damage = rand() % strength+1;
    cout << getspecies() << " inflicts " << damage
         << " damage to " << target.getspecies() << "!" << endl;
    target.takedamage(damage);
}
```

You can use `this->getspecies()` if you find just using getspecies() unclear.

Instead of srand(constant value) try something like 'srand(time(NULL))', or better still, do it once at the start of the program.